# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a+b\cdot 2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a, b>0$. I found the following series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a+b\cdot 2^n}$ is convergent by comparison test. However, I could not find an explicit expression for this sum. I was not able to apply the telescoping sum technique. I tried to get help from MAPLE, but even there, I could not obtain a closed form expression. Do you have any idea how the sum can be evaluated?

Comment: is it $b\cdot 2^n$ or $b.2^n$?

Comment: @oliverjones Edited. It is $b\cdot 2^n$

Answer (score 2):

$$S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a+b\, 2^n}=\frac 1b\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{c+ 2^n}\qquad\text{where} \quad c=\frac a b$$
To avoid the q-polygamma function
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{c+ 2^n}=\frac{\psi _{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{\log (-c)}{\log
   (2)}\right)-\log (2)}{c \log (2)}$$ we can first generate loose bounds given by the corresponding integrels

$$\color{red}{A}=\frac{\log \left(\frac{c}{2}+1\right)}{c \log (2)}~~<~~\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{c+ 2^n}~~ <~~ \frac{\log (c+1)}{c \log (2)}=\color{red}{B}$$

A simplistic *approximation* could be
$$S \sim \alpha B+(1-\alpha) A=\color{red}{C}$$ where $\alpha=\frac{31 \log(2)-16 }{16}$ gives the same unity value for $c=1$.

We still have $H > C$ with a maximum difference equal to $0.03817$ when $c=0.6092$.

Using Euler-MacLaurin summation formula
$$\large\color{red}{S \sim \frac 1b \Bigg[\frac{\log (c+2)}{c\, \log (2)}-\frac{1}{c}+\sum_{k=1 }^{6 } \frac{\beta_n}{(c+2)^k}\Bigg]}$$ where, using $\ell=\log(2)$, the coefficients are
$$\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{\ell^5-42 \ell^3+2520 \ell}{15120},\frac{42 \ell^3-5
   \ell^5}{1260},\frac{25 \ell^5-42 \ell^3}{630} ,-\frac{8
   \ell^5}{63},\frac{8 \ell^5}{63}\right\}$$

A few numbers for $b=1$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
c & \text{approximate} & \text{"exact" value} & \log_{10}(|\Delta|)\\
 1 & 0.764499793 & 0.764499780 & -7.901 \\
 2 & 0.632249853 & 0.632249890 & -7.429 \\
 3 & 0.545280262 & 0.545280273 & -7.943 \\
 4 & 0.482791615 & 0.482791612 & -8.503 \\
 5 & 0.435261411 & 0.435261403 & -8.147 \\
 6 & 0.397640144 & 0.397640137 & -8.157 \\
 7 & 0.366971415 & 0.366971409 & -8.249 \\
 8 & 0.341395810 & 0.341395806 & -8.375 \\
 9 & 0.319678582 & 0.319678578 & -8.520 \\
 10 & 0.300964037 & 0.300964035 & -8.678 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and $\cdots\cdots$ we could  do much better at the price of more terms in the summation.

To give an example, using twice more terms, for $c$ the absolute error is $1.430\times 10^{-10}$ that is to say almost $\large\color{red}{\text{100}}$ times smaller than the one given in the table.

And $\cdots\cdots$ we could  do still better at the price of more terms in the summation.

Answer (score 0):

I used Wolfram:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{a+b\cdot 2^n}=\frac{k}{a}+\frac{\psi_2^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{\pi i+\ln(a/b)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln(2)a}-\frac{\psi_2^{(0)}\left(k+1-\frac{\pi i+\ln(a/b)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln(2)a}$$
Where $\psi_q^{(n)}(z)$ is the $q$-polygamma function. So:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a+b\cdot 2^n}=\frac{\psi_2^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{\pi i+\ln(a/b)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln(2)a}+\frac{1}{a}\lim_{k\to\infty}\left[k-\frac{\psi_2^{(0)}\left(k+1-\frac{\pi i+\ln(a/b)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln(2)}\right]$$
I don't think the result can be expressed without using special functions

Comment: But how do you take the limit?

Answer (score 0):

*an answer for the most general case of
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{a+ b^n} \qquad \text{with} \quad a > 0 \qquad \text{and} \quad b >1$$
$$S=\frac{\log (a+b)}{a \log (b)}-\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{2 (a+b)}+\frac{b\log(b)}{12}\sum_{k=1}^4\frac {\log ^{2 (k-1)}(b)}{(a+b)^{2k}}\,P_k(a,b)$$

The polynomials write
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & P_k(a,b) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & \frac{-a^2+4 a b-b^2}{60}  \\
 3 & \frac{a^4-26 a^3 b+66 a^2 b^2-26 a b^3+b^4}{2520} \\
 4 & \frac{-a^6+120 a^5 b-1191 a^4 b^2+2416 a^3 b^3-1191 a^2 b^4+120 a b^5-b^6}{100800} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Trying for $a=\pi$ and $b=e$ , $S=\color{red}{0.336482}59$.